# IntelliJ Plugin - How to automatic generate Code Snippet [Java]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, generate

I am currently working on a project that is realized via an IntelliJ plugin. Unfortunately I can't find an example/guide how to set up the function for "automatic code generation".

An example would be the getter/setter methods of IntelliJ. (Alt + insert)

I would like to use "my Plugin" to build a small Java method in the current file.

It would be nice if someone would give me a tip or even a code example.

I am aware of the general structure -(plugin.xml -> `group-id="GenerateGroup"` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I still haven't found a real tutorial ...

My solution:

1. Add/Change `<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>` in your plugin.xml
2. When you use a gradle project add: `intellij { plugins 'java'` in your build.gradle

This is just my version of a new constructor

```
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e)
    {

        WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(null, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              Editor editor = e.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);

                Project project = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT);
                PsiFile file = PsiUtilBase.getPsiFileInEditor(editor, project);

                PsiJavaFile psiJavaFile = (PsiJavaFile)file;
                PsiClass[] classes = psiJavaFile.getClasses();

                PsiClass psiClass = classes[0];

                PsiElementFactory factory = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getElementFactory();
                PsiMethod newConstructor = factory.createMethodFromText("puplic " + psiClass.getName() + "() {//new Constructor }", psiClass);
                final PsiMethod[] psiMethods = psiClass.getMethods();
                PsiMethod firstMethod = (psiMethods.length == 0) ? null : psiMethods[0];
                psiClass.addBefore(newConstructor, firstMethod);
            }
        });}
```

Maybe someone could take a look at it and suggest improvements